# How to use regexp to find strings in cell array beginning and ending with a certain substring?

Tags: regex, matlab

Consider the following cell array of strings containing filenames:

```
A = { 'abcout.txt';
      'outabcd.txt';
      'outabcef.png';
      'outout.txt' }
```

I'd like to find all `.txt`-files starting with **"out"**.

I could do it as following:

```
filenames = regexp( A ,'out\w*.txt');
filenames = A( cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && x == 1,filenames) )
```

returning the desired output:

```
filenames = 

    'outabcd.txt'
    'outout.txt'
```

---

**But I wonder how I could use `regexp` to skip the `cellfun` step?**

The following almost works:

```
filenames = regexp( A ,'out\w*.txt','match');
filenames = [filenames{:}]'
```

but it returns also the first string, which is invalid (and not even correctly displayed):

```
filenames = 

    'out.txt'
    'outabcd.txt'
    'outout.txt'
```

**How do I need to modify: `'out\w*.txt'` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would modify that to

```
'^out.*\.txt$'
```

because `\w*` excludes things like

```
'out file.txt'
```

which I think should be included...Moreover, the original string is incorrect, in that it also matches

```
'outFileWtxt'
```

because you've not escaped the `.` metacharacter :)

Anyway, from a performance standpoint, getting rid of `cellfun` is actually not what you want; you should just use it properly:

```
%// dummy data
A = { 'abcout.txt';
      'outabcd.txt';
      'outabcef.png';
      'outout.txt' };

%// Make sure we have something substantial to do
A = repmat(A, 1e5,1);

%// New way   
tic
    F = regexp(A, '^out.*\.txt$', 'match');
    F = [F{:}];
toc

%// Old way with optimized cellfun() call
tic
    F = regexp(A, '^out.*\.txt$');
    F = A(~cellfun('isempty', F));
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.928403 seconds. %// without cellfun
Elapsed time is 0.471774 seconds. %// with optimized cellfun
```

This call to `cellfun` is faster because the string options refer to specific, hard-coded functions in the `cellfun` binary. This is **a lot** faster than any anonymous function will be, because *that* has to be evaluated back in the MATLAB environment.

Comment: Thanks for the additional advices, I was not considering so much exceptions before.

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` to anchor at the beginning of the string and `$` at the end of the string.

```
filenames = regexp( A ,'^out\w*.txt$');
```

Right now the `out.txt` you got from the text `abcout.txt` as you didn't use `anchor`.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex: 
^ -  states for the beginning of the line

```
^out\w*.txt
```